# How to refine the Graphcut cmex code based on a specific energy functions?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, matlab-guide, markov-models, markov-random-fields

I download the following graph-cut code:
https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex

I compiled the mex files, and ran it for pre-defined image in the code (which is rgb image)

I wanna optimize the image segmentation results,

I have probability map of the image, which its dimension is (width,height, 5). Five probability distribution over the image dimension are stacked together. each relates to one the classes.

My problem is which parts of code should according to the probability image.
I want to define Data and Smoothing terms based on my application. 
My question is:

1) Has someone refined the code according to the defining different energy function (I wanna change Unary and pair-wise formulation).

2) I have a stack of 3D images. I wanna define 6-neighborhood system, 4 neighbors in current slice and the other two from two adjacent slices. In which function and part of code can I do the refinements?

Thanks